# simplest Server-Client architecture between two programs

Tags: c#, com, network-programming, client-server, out-of-process

I want to write two simple C# programs that pass values back and forth, but the two programs will reside on two separate computers connected with an Ethernet cable.  What's best architecture to achieve this with?  Out-of-process COM components?  DLL surrogates?  Other?

I don't know anything about computer-to-computer communication, so hoping someone can let me know what I should read about to achieve my goal in the simplest way.  Does not need to be scalable to wider networks.

Answer (score 0):

after researching and reading a new book, the answer is WCF

Answer (score 0):

TCP or UDP sockets are valid alternatives.